# Convert list of dictionaries to NumPy array with grouping

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

please can someone help me, how elegantly convert this list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]
```

to this list of NumPy arrays:

```
"Cool": np.array([128,51])
"Hot": np.array([75,62])
"Archive": np.array([144,12])
```

Thank you for any clue.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    import numpy as np

data = [{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]

grouped_data = {}

for item in data:
    for key, value in item.items():
        if key in grouped_data:
            grouped_data[key].append(value)
        else:
            grouped_data[key] = [value]

for key in grouped_data:
    grouped_data[key] = np.array(grouped_data[key])

for key, value in grouped_data.items():
    print(f'"{key}": {value}')
```

Comment: You can avoid the if/else block by using a single `grouped_data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You will need a for loop inside a loop for that:

```
import numpy as np

# your data is a list
data = [{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]

# make an empty dictionary
converted_data = {}
# loop through all elements in your list
for d in data:
    # the elements in the list are dictionaries, through which you loop like this:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in converted_data: # to check if the key is already in there, keys in dictianaries need to be unique
            converted_data[key].append(value)
        else:
            converted_data[key] = [value] # 'converted_data[key]' is the way to get a value based on a key

# convert lists to numpy arrays
for key in converted_data:
    converted_data[key] = np.array(converted_data[key])

converted_data
```

Comment: You can avoid the if/else block by using a single `grouped_data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`

Comment: Cool thanks! The if-else way is more comprehensive in a rudimentary way, but it did bother me too that it's a lot of lines for not much happening. I'll leave the answer as is so the asker can decide for themself what they regard as more elegant ; ) But for sure I'll use it myself next time I come across these steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

data = [{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]

result = {}

for item in data:
    key, value = list(item.items())[0]
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = []
    result[key].append(value)

result = {key: np.array(value) for key, value in result.items()}

print(result)
```

Comment: Most straightforward, but rather use `for key, value in item.items()` rather than `key, value = list(item.items())[0]`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pandas` for this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

[pd.DataFrame(lst).melt(var_name='var',value_name='val').dropna().groupby('var')['val'].apply(np.array).to_dict()]
```

or more concise (thanks for the advice from @mozway in the comment)

```
[pd.DataFrame(lst).stack().groupby(level=1).apply(np.array).to_dict()]
```

and you will obtain

```
[{'Archive': array([144.,  12.]),
  'Cool': array([128.,  51.]),
  'Hot': array([75., 62.])}]
```

## data

```
lst = [{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]
```

Comment: I would really not use pandas for that, this will create a large 2D intermediate with many NaNs and be slower than a pure python loop. You can avoid the `dropna` by using `stack` in place of `melt` (`pd.DataFrame(lst).stack().groupby(level=1).apply(np.array).to_dict()`) ;)

Comment: @mozway haha, I agree. In this case simple loop is the most efficient and straightforward option.

Comment: @mozway thanks for your contribution, I updated the solution with your advice!

Answer (score 0):

A handy tool for grouping is `collections.defaultdict`.  You define a dict that takes an default initial value if the key is not found.  It's a streamlined version of the `setdefault` that @mozway has been suggesting.

```
In [19]: alist = [{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]

In [20]: from collections import defaultdict
In [21]: dd = defaultdict(list) # initial
In [22]: dd
Out[22]: defaultdict(list, {})
```

then fill it from the list.  The 2nd loop lets us have more than one key in a dict.  Knowing/assuming each dict has only one key doesn't make this any faster or simpler

```
In [23]: for d in alist:
    ...:     for k in d:
    ...:         dd[k].append(d[k])
    ...:         

In [24]: dd
Out[24]: defaultdict(list, {'Cool': [128, 51], 'Hot': [75, 62], 'Archive': [144, 12]})
```

It could be converted to a dict of array values with:

```
In [25]: dd1={k:np.array(v) for k,v in dd.items()}

In [26]: dd1
Out[26]: 
{'Cool': array([128,  51]),
 'Hot': array([75, 62]),
 'Archive': array([144,  12])}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a code

```
import numpy as np

data = [{'Cool': 128}, {'Cool': 51}, {'Hot': 75}, {'Hot': 62}, {'Archive': 144}, {'Archive': 12}]


result_dict = {}

for d in data:

    for key, value in d.items():
    
        if key not in result_dict:
            result_dict[key] = []
    
        result_dict[key].append(value)


result_dict_np = {key: np.array(value) for key, value in result_dict.items()}

for key, value in result_dict_np.items():
    print(f'"{key}": {value}')
```